# Setting a Campaign Member RecordType automatically based on the Campaign RecordType

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

So far I've seen the Campaign Member Record Type is set based on the `Campaign Member Type` field which the Campaign has.

**What I need is to set the Campaign Member RT based on the Campaign's RT**. Is there any way of doing this?

So far I've tried with Workflows and Process Builder, but the field wasn't available, which leaves me only to triggers. The problem is I wanted a fairly standard way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `CampaignMember` records associated to a Campaign record possess the same RecordTypeId. The field used to determine the RecordTypeId is `CampaignMemberRecordTypeId` and it is present on Campaign Object. I came across a scenario some time back where I could not use Workflow to update the RecordTyepId on CampaignMember. So, I ended up writing an Apex trigger that updates the `CampaignMemberRecordTypeId` field present on Campaign object.